# Laravel 5 Directory served instead of route

Tags: laravel

I recently installed Laravel on my Ubuntu using composer, in the /var/www/html folder.

When i go to my directory however I am not served the Laravel welcome message, I just get Apache showing me all the files and folders in the directory.

My routes.php indicates that welcome.blade.php should be showed as default, i havent edited this, so im confused why it is not being served.

Please let me know what i might be doing wrong, if navigating to myip/myprojectdirectory

Comment: The application runs from `public/index.php`. Your Apache install's DocumentRoot should be pointed at the `public` directory.

Comment: @ceejayoz do I do this in the htaccess file? I don't see one already There. Thank you!!!

Comment: No, you do it in the Apache config files.